# How to add custom column based on a table - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a query in which I need to add a column (is_found) on the base of another table "history", if product_id exists on a table "history" then the column value (is_found) became 1 otherwise its value remains 0.

Here is my query:

```
Product::select(
    'products.id as product_id',
    'products.name',
    'products.desc',
    'products.image',
    'products.barcode',
    'categories.name as category_name',
    'categories.id as category_id',
)
    ->leftJoin(
        'categories',
        'products.category_id',
        '=',
        'categories.id'
    )
```

Comment: This is typically what you'd use Eloquent relations for. Define a model for your Product, and one for your Category, and make the relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Product::select(
    'products.id as product_id',
    'products.name',
    'products.desc',
    'products.image',
    'products.barcode',
    'categories.name as category_name',
    'categories.id as category_id',
    \DB::raw('IF(history.product_id, 1, 0) AS is_found')
)
    ->leftJoin(
        'categories',
        'products.category_id',
        '=',
        'categories.id'
    )
   ->leftJoin('history', 'products.id','=','history.product_id')
```

Or:

```php
Product::select(
    'products.id as product_id',
    'products.name',
    'products.desc',
    'products.image',
    'products.barcode',
    'categories.name as category_name',
    'categories.id as category_id',
    \DB::raw('IF((select product_id from history where history.product_id = products.id), 1, 0)')
)
    ->leftJoin(
        'categories',
        'products.category_id',
        '=',
        'categories.id'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub-select` with `exists`

```
Product::select(
    'products.id as product_id',
    'products.name',
    'products.desc',
    'products.image',
    'products.barcode',
    'categories.name as category_name',
    'categories.id as category_id',
)
->selectRaw('exists (select * from history where history.product_id = products.id) as is_found')
->leftJoin('categories', 'products.category_id', '=','categories.id')
```